# Android smootScrollToPosition is not working properly. Why?

Tags: android, listview

Before yesterday smoothScrollToPosition was working perfectly, however, I did some design (adding background picture) to my listview.item file. Then my lv.smoothScrollToPosition(result.size()-1) did not work fully. It works only when last item is displayed. It does not work when I scroll it to upside. setSelection method works fine. However, I need smooth movement.

Here is my function:

```
playGround.notifyDataSetChanged();

activity.getLv().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
          activity.getLv().smoothScrollToPosition(result.size()-1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used this method. But I do not know why it works.

```
activity.getLv().post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
              activity.getLv().smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(result.size(),0, 700);
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
playGround.notifyDataSetChanged();

activity.getLv().post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
          activity.getLv().smoothScrollToPosition(result.size());
    }
});
```